# Asymmetric Suzuki coupling - saturated alkyl chain

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, transition-metals

9-BBN is applied for Suzuki coupling of a saturated alkyl chain with some alkenyl,alkynyl or even secondary alkyl halide like the modification attached:

[image: B. Saito, G. C. Fu, J. Am. Chem. Soc., 2007, 129, 9602–9603.]

(Saito, B.; Fu, G. C. Alkyl−Alkyl Suzuki Cross-Couplings of Unactivated Secondary Alkyl Halides at Room Temperature. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **2007,** *129,* 9602–9603. [DOI:10.1021/ja074008l.](http://doi.org/10.1021/ja074008l))

For asymmetric hydroboration another bulky group is used - Ipc:
[image]

Is there an asymmetric version of Suzuki coupling employing saturated groups where instead of 9-BBN, Icp or a similar chiral group would be used or would the stereochemical information be lost during transmetallation?

EDIT: I've found this reaction sequence in Carey, Sundberg Advanced Org. Chem:
[image]

The product could be used for a Suzuki couping, but the question whether the stereochemical information is lost during coupling remains open.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2929007/ your asking about?

Comment: That article explains the enantioselectivity in the case of chiral halide, I am asking about chiral organoboranes.

Comment: As of 2010, when I wrote my thesis and papers on the alkyl-alkyl couplings, I do not believe there were any asymmetric variants using a chiral borane.

Comment: I found this reference, but I don't have access to read it: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo201263r Amusingly, I worked with Liz also when we were both in the Jacobsen lab.

Comment: Oh, so it is possible.

Comment: Maybe that's not surprising. The transmetallation and reductive elimination steps are most likely concerted and not reversible.